# Wireless 4311 card not working

Tags: broadcom

HELP.

```
simon@simon-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:23:24:77:ba
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 duplex=full firmware=5755m-v3.29 ip=10.1.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:fe7f0000-fe7fffff
```

Comment: Solved by:udo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

login ubuntu program center, 
search b43 find

firmware-b43-installer
and instal.

Or Look :http://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=765.0

Comment: Could you add a bit more information as to why it works (E.g. "The default 44 driver is not compatible. Get the older 4.3 driver. You do that with these commands"). Even if you do that by partially copying or translating the information on the other site you linked to (which might not be available in the future).